# How to intercept LLVM lli tool input?

Tags: llvm, interpreter

I'd like to use LLVM `lli` tool as static library (rename `main()` to `lli()` and export it in libLLi.a) - to create rich UI for it. How can i modify it (or use without modifications) in order to intercept stdin?

Assume i know how to generate LLVM assembly file  (using `clang -S -emit-llvm .. -o output.ll`) and how to execute it using `lli` tool (`lli output.ll`).

Common use case:

Source code of simple app to be interpreted by lli:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char name[128]; 
    cout << "type your name: ";
    cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));
    cout << "hi, " << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I need to interpret LLVM assembly for it and to show InputBox when `cin.getline` invoked and show TextBox when `cout <<` invoked (InputBox and TextBox are rich UI controls).

PS. I can't fork process and forward stdin/stdout of the whole child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lli` is already a thin wrapper around llvm library functions, just use those instead. The main() function in `tools/lli/lli.cpp` is long only because it supports tons of flags to control every possible setting. After you strip it down it should be less than 10 lines to create an [`ExecutionEngine`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html) using an `EngineBuilder` and use it to run a `llvm::Function`.

You might also find [chapter 4 of the Kaleidoscope tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl04.html) helpful, where they add JIT support to the language. This also demonstrates how to use an EngineBuilder, though the ExecutionEngine they choose to build is a `JIT` instead of an `Interpreter`, you can customize it for your use case.

Now for the other part of your question, how do you trap `stdin` and `stdout`? LLVM is not a VM, the code is running in your process and using your stdin and stdout. My first suggestion is that since you already have the function in LLVM IR format, just run a transformation pass that replaces standard I/O functions with your own I/O functions. A simpler way to do that if you can get the ABI to line up, is to do the remapping with the ExecutionEngine. Call `EE->updateGlobalMapping(functionDeclInIR, &replacementFunctionInNativeCode)` to tell the ExecutionEngine that the `Function*` for functionDeclInIR is represented in native code by replacementFunctionInNativeCode. You would need to provide your own implementation of _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc (aka. ostream::operator<<) which uses your GUI.

Comment: sounds promising. any suggestions/examples/links on how to write `ostream::operator<<` inheritor?